Chrome Browser: XHR Request Error net::Err_Failed 200 on Subsequent Requests
I've discovered a download issue connected to free disk space limited to the Chrome or Chromium browser. The app is a media player which runs on a dedicated PC, regardless of the low disk space there is still plenty of space for the download.
Simple code example...
function _startDownloadBackground() {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        httpRequest.open('GET', 'images/background.mp4', true);
        httpRequest.responseType = 'blob';
        httpRequest.onload = () => {
            console.log('success');
        };
        httpRequest.onerror = () => {
            console.log('fail');
        };

        httpRequest.send();
    }

Run this code locally removing any remote server considerations, background.mp4 is a 15 MB file (any size will produce the same results). Use Chome or Chromium as the browser.
When your PC's disk space is normal (no red bar for the Local Disk space in the Explorer), the above function will download the mp4 on each execution. However, when disk space is low, but still more than enough to store the mp4 (in this example 1.5GB is free) you'll experience the following...

Open Chrome > execute the function = success
Execute the function = Err_Failed 200
Refresh the browser > execute the function = Err_Failed 200
Open Dev Tools > Disable Cache > execute the function = Err_Failed
200
Hard refresh > execute function = Err_failed
Close Chome > open Chrome > execute the function = success
Replay a failed xhr by right-clicking the failed request in dev tools = success

This is not an issue in Edge or Firefox. I've tried opening Chrome with the following switches with no luck.
--disk-cache-size=104857600 | --aggressive-cache-discard | --enable-aggressive-domstorage-flushing
Finally, I've taken a log from chrome://net-export/ and noticed two interesting entries (both on different requests)

HTTP_CACHE_DOOM_ENTRY  [dt=0] --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=1] (no request for URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ) then the next line reads 'Cancelled'


I caught in your message because I had the same behaviour. Don't tell me why but this problem started to happen when my free disk was low. removing unusued files worked again. Thanks

And what is ERR_FAILED supposed to mean?
I suggest you improve your error checking by taking advantage of X.status, X.readyState and X.statusText, so that you can see exactly what's going on.
httpRequest.onerror =()=>{

 console.log(this.status+' - '+this.readyState+' - '+this.statusText);

};

And if that doesn't work use another method...
httpRequest.onerror =(e)=>{

 console.log(e+' - '+e.message);

};

So find a way to return meaningful error reporting so that you can make an informed decision towards a resolution.
You should never be satisfied with daft error reporting like… “fail” or “error” or “oops” because they’re all utterly useless!

The readyState is clearly 4 which is why it's returning a 200. Status and statusText return 0 and an empty string.  The event or event. target doesn't have a message property. Hopefully, you can see from my research this isn't your typical badly formed request, network issue or server problem.
